# Does Conrad Tesdinic turn up in other stories?

Tags: chrestomanci, diana-wynne-jones

In "[Conrad's Fate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conrad's_Fate)" by Diana Wynne Jones, the main character is Conrad Tesdinic.

During the story he meets Christopher and Millie, who turn up in other stories in the Chrestomanci series.  At the end of this book, Conrad is about to go and meet the King and find out what his future job will be. He is talking to a friend, Fay Marley.

It seems to me that this is being set up for Conrad's story to continue.  Even if he doesn't have a large story (like Chrestomanci!) does he show up in the background or as a minor character, in another story?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is the only book he shows up in. Sadly we'll never know if Ms. Jones ever planned a larger story arc for him.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I was just hoping someone had seen him somewhere! (Like Carol Oneir's father, who hit the future Chrestomanci with a cricket bat as a child.)